# How did the several different species of Lard in Adventure Time come to exist?

Tags: adventure-time

How did the several different species of Lard in *Adventure Time* come to exist? What evolutionary process caused such a vast range of lard? E.g. Space Lards in space, Grass Lards on grass, Sea Lards in the sea.

How did Lards come to be?